# Why doesn't the NetworkManager GUI need sudo privileges?

Tags: permissions, network-manager

As a normal user, I can create network connections and VPN configurations via the NetworkManager GUI as desired, and the configuration files end up in the write-protected `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory. However, if I try to directly create system-connections configuration files via, say, the terminal, I get a permission error. For example

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ 
$ touch WifiWhenYouCanDrive
touch: cannot touch 'WifiWhenYouCanDrive': Permission denied
```

Why is it that a normal (non-sudo) can write files to a write-protected directory using the NetworkManager GUI? Shouldn't it require elevated privileges to write configuration files to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`?

Comment: In a word - [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NetwotkManager GUI asks the NetworkManager daemon to make the needed changes. This daemon runs as root so it has the privileges to change the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Florian  said, Network Manager indicator  communicates via dbus. It's a communication bus for different processes, and allows to execute certain functions on behalf of the user

Comment: Comment? Answer? Commentanswer? :P